# Black screen trying to install ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, screen

Im having trouble installing the os in my computer. I get to the screen menu where it gives you the options to install or to test before installing. Whenever i Press install my screen goes black for a few seconds and then turns off completely. Nothing happens after that.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this and find out if this is my pc or the usb? Im really new to all tech stuff too.

Comment: Did you format your usb stick when you put the Ubuntu iso on it?

Comment: Hi. I formatted it as free space and then used the terminal commands to create the image on the usb :(

Comment: What type of graphics card does it have? It would either be Nvidia, AMD, or run from the cpu.

Comment: Is an Nvidia GTX 970!

Comment: Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/400278) out it seems like the same problem that you are having.